# Easiest way to write the single char よ in math mode

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, unicode, japanese

I'm looking forward to use よ ([Hiragana Letter Yo](https://unicode-table.com/en/3088/)) in math mode, to denote the [Yoneda embedding.](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Yoneda+embedding). Is there a way to typeset just this char, without importing a whole Japanese font?

Comment: you can make a small pdf of just that character and then `\includegraphics{..}`

Comment: @campa it might be it. As soon as I can try it I'll reach back.